# MSChart X-Axis Dates

Tags: c#, .net, charts, mschart

I am plotting a simple line graph like the following:

[image]

Recently a Customer had the requirement to change the interval on the graph so that each data point was right next to each other, and no dates are between them.

For example, the graph below would have 6 x-values and they would all be evenly spaced, and have the same dates 3-8-12, 3-24-12,4-4-12,4-13-12,4-15-12,4-17-12. We don't care about the dates in-between.

How can I do this in MSChart?

Comment: + 1 ) Good Quesrion :) How are you binding the chart with the data?. I am not too sure on the syntax of C# but in VB.Net we use the ` Chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Table1")` if we are binding the chart with the Dataset. And if you are using dataset then you can actually create a new Dataset which has the filtered values and then bind that with the chart? Also are you using VS 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the  `Series.IsXValueIndexed = true;`

http://support2.dundas.com/Default.aspx?article=909